# How to make button movable in google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am making a GUI-based data management system using google sheet and app script. I have inserted two buttons using the draw option. But I cannot move that button to the bottom of the sheet where it needs to be. Whenever I tried to move that button a red line is appearing there; as you can see on the image. So please help me what should I do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v0sj.png)

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

The red line in simply a rule line. Its purpose is to help you line up the drawings. In your screenshot, the rule line shows that the bottom of `Update` currently lines up with the bottom of `Next`.

You can go ahead and drag across the line to move a drawing further down. To make drag and drop easier, you may want to temporarily unassign scripts in the buttons, or select a button by *right*-clicking it and then move it using the arrow keys rather than the mouse.

Comment: I appreciate your help but unfortunately, this is not working.

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) where the issue can be reproduced.